# Why do I get this discord.py error on my VPS but not my home PC?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu, discord.py

I'm making a discord bot in python, and when I run it on my windows 10 pc it runs fine, but if I run it on my ubuntu VPS it gives me a massive error.

Windows 10 python version: 3.9
Ubuntu version: 3.5 (I don't think 3.9 is on ubuntu, I cant find it anywhere)

Error:

````
  File "bot.py", line 1923, in <module>
    client.run(config.token)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 519, in run
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self.start(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/base_events.py", line 387, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/futures.py", line 274, in result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/asyncio/tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 491, in start
    yield from self.connect()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 448, in connect
    yield from self.ws.poll_event()
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 431, in poll_event
    yield from self.received_message(msg)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/gateway.py", line 390, in received_message
    func(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 509, in parse_guild_create
    server = self._get_create_server(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/state.py", line 483, in _get_create_server
    server._from_data(data)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/server.py", line 218, in _from_data
    self._sync(guild)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/server.py", line 250, in _sync
    channel = Channel(server=self, **c)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 89, in __init__
    self._update(**kwargs)
  File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/channel.py", line 116, in _update
    self._permission_overwrites.append(Overwrites(**overridden))
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'deny_new'
Task was destroyed but it is pending!
task: <Task pending coro=<ConnectionState._delay_ready() running at /home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/discord/state.py:173> wait_for=<Future pending cb=[Task._wakeup()]>>```
````

Comment: If you type `python3 --version` in your console, is it =3.5.0?

Comment: `discord.py` supports python 3.5.3+ if you have a lower version you can simply upgrade to 3.8 or any higher version, there's no problem with that

Comment: my python3 version is 3.5.2

Comment: As @ŁukaszKwieciński pointed out, `discord.py` doesn't support versions older than 3.5.3. But python3.9 absolutely exists on ubuntu, does running `sudo apt get install python3.9` not work?